# How to change text in multiple lines / places of a Textbox in FabricJS?

Tags: algorithm, fabricjs

I need to replace text of particular selection when the input value has been changed.

- On the initial rendering, I get an object of selections and fields.
- Secondly, inputs get values of fields.

[image]

Assume I'm changing a value of the **Line** input, since this field controls two lines, both of those green texts should be replaced with the new one.

http://jsfiddle.net/hkvmLwfu/

Tnx

```js
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////// THIS FUNCTION NEEDS TO BE DEVELOPED ////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function replaceTextBySelection(fieldId, fieldValue, canvas, text){

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('paper');
canvas.setHeight(300);
canvas.setWidth(500);

var text = new fabric.Textbox('Sample Line 1 Line 2 Line 3', {
  left: 50,
  top: 10,
  fontFamily: 'arial',
  fill: '#333',
  fontSize: 50
});
canvas.add(text);
canvas.renderAll();

const fields = {
 FIELD_1: {
     value: "Sample",
        color: '#F00'
    },
    FIELD_2: {
     value: "Line",
        color: '#0F0'
    }
}

selections = [
    {
        rowId: 0,
        offset: 0,
        length: 6,
        field: "FIELD_1"
    },
    {
        rowId: 1,
        offset: 0,
        length: 4,
        field: "FIELD_2"
    },
    {
        rowId: 2,
        offset: 0,
        length: 4,
        field: "FIELD_2"
    }
]

selections.map((obj)=>{
    text.setSelectionStart(obj.offset);
    text.setSelectionEnd(obj.offset + obj.length);
    text.setSelectionStyles();

    for (let i = text.selectionStart; i < text.selectionEnd; i++) {
      text.insertCharStyleObject(obj.rowId, i, {
        textBackgroundColor: fields[obj.field].color
      })
    }
    canvas.renderAll();
    return obj;
});

$('#FIELD_1').val( fields['FIELD_1'].value );
$('#FIELD_2').val( fields['FIELD_2'].value );


$("input").keyup(function(t){
 replaceTextBySelection(this.id, this.value, canvas, text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="paper" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
<input type="text" id="FIELD_1" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="FIELD_2" />
```

Comment: Is it a requirement that all your text remains in a single Fabric text object? Or could each line be divided up into its own text object? Latter approach could make this much easier to manage.

Comment: It must to remain the same Texrbox object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example complicates things because the `selections` object reasons about rows, but the text doesn't actually contain rows, only spaces that get wrapped to a new line.

It gets easier if you define your text instead as

`var text = new fabric.Textbox('Sample\nLine 1\nLine 2\nLine 3', {
  left: 50,
  top: 10,
  fontFamily: 'arial',
  fill: '#333',
  fontSize: 50
});`

Using this text I have created a functional example: http://jsfiddle.net/hkvmLwfu/12/. I'm not sure this is entirely how you want it, but you should be able to pick it up from here.

Comment: Seppe Lenders. Working great only if you update a text with a variable input...
If you will add a new line, let's say between 1st and 2nd rows, logic will collapse...
Any idea how to combine editing from both variants?

Comment: Plus, if you have 2 selections on the same line, it also has some issues with updates.

Comment: I have updated my solution to support multiple selections on the same line. I'm not sure what you mean with your first comment. Can you clarify which kinds of input break my solution?

Comment: Don't worry about the first one... I've made a change to support it...
It's a combination of your and my code...
http://jsfiddle.net/redlive/hkvmLwfu/10/

Basically, if you click inside of Textbox itself and try to add a line, all selections should be updated, which isn't in your case...

Anyways, thank you for your help !

Comment: Btw... forgot to ask you... Is there any way to support EMPTY values as well? Try to remove value from an input...

Comment: Hmm. fabric.js's insertChars method doesn't seem to like strings of length 0 or selections of length 1. I have updated my version to support empty strings: http://jsfiddle.net/hkvmLwfu/12/. It doesn't work with your version though, but maybe you can adapt it yourself.

Comment: Yes... You are right... It won't because your version doesn't support adding text before selection and also new lines... Your version relies on initial selection object only, although a client may change a text and that initial selection object won't be relevant anymore. Selection needs to be recalculated...

Answer (score 0):

Just use `\n` where you want to break the line. It will work like `<br/>`.